# how to assign dedicated thread to specific spring mvc rest request method

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-mvc, jetty-9

Is it possible to assign dedicated thread to specific control method? am using jetty server. jetty server handling QueuedThreadPool logic. my problem is i have domainname/app/list service. when ever this service called i need to use same thead. but jetty server assain thread using QueuedThreadPool. but this case my service handling diffrent threads. becouse of this application blocking ?

when server started first service request it assigned threadqtp-10. then onwards i need to use same thread for that particular service method? i know it this is not related to spring. this totally jetty server configuration...

Problem in details

My application runnging in jetty server and same system act as server and client. only server configured system can access this application.

one of my service domainname/app/list it preocess the business logic. so when ever server starts first if i try to access domainname/app/list service . in this case jetty server will assian threadqtp-10. once this completes it return response back.here after again when i try to access same service i need to execute same thread threadqtp-10 then only my business logic accept and return success. othere wise it return invalid thread access error.

finally i need inform jetty server when ever domainname/app/list service request comes please use only theadqtp-10 only . there is no case two or more request will access this service. at a time one request can access this service.
Thanks.

Comment: Even if possible, in practice this would fail in scaling.  Imagine 100 worker threads all trying to use one thread for a particular service.  You're going to need to explain your problem in more detail for any of us to offer a solution.

Comment: @JohnVint thanks for ur reply. i have edited my question in detail , can u help me?